# What is the algorithm behind OCR?

Tags: ocr

I'm curious about the algorithm and basic principles behind [Optical Character Recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition).

Can anyone explain:

- The most basic OCR algorithm that can be fairly easily implemented from scratch? Or the common denominator between different OCR algorithms?
- Extensions/changes made to tailor the algorithm for application specific goals?

Also see my [follow up question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3006/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-different-ocr-methods) on OCR.

Comment: This question is a little too broad. You're practically asking for a book reference. Narrowing it down a bit would help getting answers. For what it's worth, do some research on number 1 (hint: the answer is that there are *many* different algorithms with different steps). The second bullet point is perhaps the best basis for a question. The third could be a follow-up question all by itself.

Comment: The simplest scheme is probably the original MICR scheme, where a special font is used that is designed to be easy to read, and where the lines of characters are cleanly aligned under the reader with BOT/EOT markers.

Comment: @Phonon, I created a follow up question, and changed the question a bit to narrow the scope. Hope this is better now.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest OCR algorithm would be the case where the characters are from a known font, in perfect rows with no distortion or rotation, and then you can find occurrences of each character in the text by doing cross-correlation with the known characters from the known font.

Or even simpler if you can create the font before it's used, with cheaper ways to recognize characters, like the [MICR fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_ink_character_recognition) or [OCR fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCR-A_font).